# Disable button 1 Section when click on button 2

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Have multiple buttons and sections associated with those buttons in the Elementor page builder.

What I am trying to achieve is when page loads, we can only see buttons and section will toggle when someone clicks on the button.

I have managed to achieve that, but when clicking on second button, button 1 section should hide and button 2 section should display.

Here is the [w3 schools link for my project](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GH2U3FWWUW9J)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    
  var hbtn = $(".coursesBtn");
  var hcon = $(".coursesSection");
  
   hcon.hide();
   hbtn.click(function(e) {
   var index = hbtn.index(this) 
   $(hcon).eq(index).slideToggle("slow");

   e.preventDefault();     
    });
});
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    
  var hbtn = $(".videosBtn");
  var hcon = $(".videosSection");
  
   hcon.hide();
   hbtn.click(function(e) {
   var index = hbtn.index(this) 
   $(hcon).eq(index).slideToggle("slow");

   e.preventDefault();     
    });
});
```

Comment: can you add a basic HTML to mock up the scenario?

Comment: Here is the w3 schools link where i am working https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GH2U3FWWUW9J

Comment: please review the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick` for buttons for example

```
<button class="btn1" onclick="f1()">BUTTON1</button>
```

and add the function to toggle in `f1()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example, the idea is to hide the other sections first, and show the section that you want to be displayed;

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.btn1').click(function() {
    $('.section').hide();
    $('.section1').show();
  })

  $('.btn2').click(function() {
    $('.section').hide();
    $('.section2').show();
  })

  $('.btn3').click(function() {
    $('.section').hide();
    $('.section3').show();
  })

})
```

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.section3 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn1">BUTTON1</button>
<button class="btn2">BUTTON2</button>
<button class="btn3">BUTTON3</button>

<div class="section section1">
  This is Section1.
</div>
<div class="section section2">
  This is Section2.
</div>
<div class="section section3">
  This is Section3.
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class for each button (`.btn`) and section (`.section`) and use these as in the code below. You can have as many buttons and sections as you want and the code below will work without any modification:

```
var hbtn = $(".btn");
var hcon = $(".section");  
hcon.hide();
hbtn.click(function(e) {
    var index = hbtn.index(this); 
    hcon.hide() //OR hcon.filter(':visible').slideToggle("slow")
    .eq(index).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function( $ ){  
    var hbtn = $(".btn");
    var hcon = $(".section");  
    hcon.hide();
    hbtn.click(function(e) {
        var index = hbtn.index(this);
        hcon.hide() //OR hcon.filter(':visible').slideToggle("slow")
        .eq(index).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.section1 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.section2 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1 btn">BUTTON1</button>
<button class="btn2 btn">BUTTON2</button>

<div class="section1 section">
This is Section1.
</div>
<div class="section2 section">
This is Section2.
</div>
```